# Is there way to have some code both in lexer and parser members in combined grammar?

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I have a utility method which I use in both lexer and parser -generated code in a combined grammar. Other than moving it to an external utility class, is there some way to get rid of copy/paste to members and lexer::members, and have this method emitted both in generated Lexer, and Parser?

I am using Antlr 3... I guess if there's something new that is added in 4 that would also be useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is placed in either the parser, or the lexer (both for v3 and v4). If possible, you could, of course, make it static so that it's easily called from both.